# Django Forms - Specify ModelForm model at Submit?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am working on creating a form that can save data to one of four tables based on the model the user picks from a different view. I don't want to create the same form for each model though.

Is there a way to pass the model name to the form when the user clicks submit?

Here is the code:

models.py

```
class TagModel(MP_Node):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    generic_objecttag_set = GenericRelation('ObjectTag')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('slug',),
        )
        abstract = True


class Concept(TagModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Concepts'


class Difficulty(TagModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Difficulty'

class QuestionType(TagModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Question Type'

class QuestionFormat(TagModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Question Format'
```

forms.py

```
class TagModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TagModelForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data['slug'] = slugify(cleaned_data.get('name', ''))
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = models.TagModelForm
        fields = ('slug', 'name',)
        widgets = {
            'slug': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

views.py

```
class TagCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = forms.TagModelForm
    template_name = 'tags/create.html'


    @method_decorator(permission_required('tags.add_tag'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        arg_model = kwargs.get('tree_name', None)
        if arg_model:
            self.curr_model = get_model('tags', arg_model)
        return super(TagCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        curr_model = self.curr_model
        curr_model.add_root(**data)
        return super(TagCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('tags:index')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible. Sounds like it's better to use form inheritance. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance

Comment: Try to override form's `__init__` method. 
```def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
   self._meta.model = <put here model from data var or where from you nee>
   super(TagModelForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)```

Comment: Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/users/897413/der-fenix. Will I need to instantiate the form and pass the model from the view? How do I actually do that from the view?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely try form inheritance and do something like:

```
class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean():
        #...
    # whatever other methods here, etc.


class ConceptTagForm(TagForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Concept

class DifficultyTagForm(TagForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Difficulty
# etc
```